# Error message when using v.in.ascii in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, ascii

I'm trying to follow the [this GRASS tutorial](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Triangle_Mesh#How_to_create_a_3D_TIN) and I'm already stuck at the first step. I have acii points in an .xyz and supposed to import them with v.in.ascii. However, I get the following error message

> WARNING: Expected 5 columns, found 4 columns
>   ERROR: Broken row 384: '32346000.00 5630383.00  100.01'
>   (Sun Feb  2 16:02:14 2020) Befehl ausgeführt (0 Sek)
>   (Sun Feb  2 16:05:43 2020)
>   v.in.ascii -n input=C:\Users\denni\Desktop\xyz_daten\dgm1.xyz output=dgm1 separator=space text=space z=4

I don't find the setting to tell the algorithm to expect only 4 columns.

That's the content of the ascii file:

[image]

And that's the settings under the "point" field:

[image]

how can I solve the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is failing when your 4th column has a 3-digit number (100.01) rather than the 2-digit numbers you show in your screenshot (98.xx).

Your data file is poorly formatted and uses whitespace as a delimiter rather than a `,` or `|` or other character. Because of this, when your number grows to `100.01` it eats up one of the spaces that makes the invisible 3rd column. I have no idea where the 5th column is. Perhaps to the right of your `98.xx` numbers?

I suggest reformatting your data file. Replace spaces with a comma, and collapse to only 3 columns.

If you try to do this with only 4 columns, that won't work either - when the digit grows to >= 100, you'll probably read in NaNs rather than the data, because it has shifted columns at that point.